# How can I make a bordered circle button expand into a bordered pill button on hover in Unity, and still maintain the border thickness?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, user-interface

I'm using Unity 2019.2.5f1, and I'm trying to create some dynamic UI buttons that would operate as such...

Clean bordered button when not hovered, see below:

[image: 1]

then, it automagically animates and elongates into a clean and constant bordered pill button when hovered and pressed, like this:

[image: 2]

**The Issue:** I'm trying to use one sprite (the circular one) to accomplish all of this, however when the circular button expands to the pill button, the border becomes distorted. Like this:
[image: 3]

Editor Settings:

[image: 4]

Current 9-Slicing:

[image: 5]

I've tried several 9-slices on the sprite, one with just a left to right slice down the centerline of the circle. One with a small sliver between the left and right slices. One with the circle sprite split into four quadrants, with all slices down the. These all seem to cause similar behavior. I feel like this is a simple thing to fix...alas, my efforts have been thwarted.

Comment: Can you show your inspector with your image component configuration, and your sprite editor with you 9-slicing the button into 4 quadrants?

Comment: @ErikOverflow added, thanks!

Comment: I have zero experience with C# or Unity, but is it possible to make a "group" of elements: one circle (left), one circle (right) and a rectangle on top of them in the middle. On hover, the rectangle width expands.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I managed to achieve what you're trying to do. Here are my settings:

The image slicing:
[image]

The button settings:
Make sure the button's Image is set to Sliced mode.
[image]

To increase the flat portions of the sides, increase the Pixel per units multiplier in the button's Image component.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I've manged to get a similar result to that previously, however, my desired result (picture number 2) has completely rounded sides with no flat portions on the left and right. So basically like your chopping the circle vertically down the middle and then stretching it left and right and and filling the middle.

Comment: Hey! I just updated my answer. You can increase the Pixels per unit multiplier to get more flat surface.

Comment: This worked! Thanks. I changed the 'Pixels per unit' to 1.6 and that pretty much did the trick. There's still a little, very minor, bit of distortion that you can catch during the animation - but i think that's just me being critical :)